# How should a weak jointed man handle being drawn into doing kids yoga?

Tags: yoga, children

My son is five. He loves doing Cosmic Kids Yoga on youtube. I am fine with doing yoga but after my weightlifting program and with other restriction I can't really do yoga. I have so many bad joints and other areas- sub-clinical. How do I prevent injuries if he presses me into doing his type yoga (he is a normal five year old so he is very flexible)?

Comment: I don't understand what makes you say "I can't really do yoga".

Comment: It hurts  during and afterwards. This type has fast transitions and large motions.

Comment: I mean, you have you draw some lines here. What would you do if he asked you to partake in something that was even more harmful? It's more important to explain how not all people can do everything, than it is to try and mitigate damage from something that might inherently harm you. As a tip, there is also https://parenting.stackexchange.com if you need some input on how to explain it.

Comment: I would be happy to do it if it didn't hurt. It is fun.

Answer (score 3):

There are usually some modified, less strenuous poses you can take that will help you on the way to opening locked muscles and poses not accessable to you at this moment, or you can use props to modify the height of the floor or get better balance. It's all dependent on the poses and difficult to say without seeing you in action.

As you say, your son is five, and is still naturally flexible. The teacher has probably done yoga for several years, and have practiced a lot. As with everything things take practice and that takes time.

As a general principle, yoga should not hurt. Although it can be strenuous and *feel a lot*. But not painful - there is a difference. Generally sharp pain should be avoided, while intense feelings can be endured, depending on the intensity of the feeling and your own judgement. You say you're doing weights, so I assume you're somewhat familiar with your body. As with weights, don't force yourself outside of your limits, and slowly with increasing the "load".